# Evaluate modular power towers

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

Given two numbers n and m, evaluate the infinite power tower:

> n^(n+1)^(n+2)^(n+3)^(n+4)^... mod m

Keep in mind that ^ is right-associative. So 2^3^4 = 2^(3^4). Now how can  you possibly assign a value to an infinite sequence of right-associative operators?

Define f(n,m,i) as the power tower containing the first i terms of the infinite power tower. Then there is some constant C such that for every i > C, f(n,m,i) = f(n,m,C). So you could say the infinite power tower converges on a certain value. We're interested in that value.

---

Your program must be able to compute n = 2017, m = 10^10 in under 10 seconds on a reasonable modern PC. That is, you should implement an actual algorithm, no bruteforcing.

You may assume that *n < 2<sup>30</sup>* and *m* < 2<sup>50</sup> for the numerical limits in your programming language, but your algorithm must theoretically work for any size *n*, *m*. However your program **must** be correct for inputs within these size limits, intermediate value overflows are **not** excused if the inputs are within these limits.

Examples:

```
2, 10^15
566088170340352

4, 3^20
4

32, 524287
16
```

Comment: Tip (for contenders): `n` and `m` are **not** guaranteed to be co-prime.

Comment: 10^10 (and 10^20, and potentially 3^20 for signed integers) is larger than many languages' default integer types. Is it required that this large of an input be supported?

Comment: @orlp Does that "yes" include 10^20? Because that doesn't fit in a 64-bit integer, so if you want to require it, I'd suggest pointing it out explicitly, because otherwise you're going to get a lot of invalid answers by people just assuming that 64 bit integers are going to be accurate enough.

Comment: Either way, what *is* the largest input we need to support?

Comment: @Doorknob I added more lenient limits to the challenge. However your algorithm must theoretically work for any size _m, n_.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 23 bytes

```
M&tG.^HsgBu-G/GH{PGGhHG
```

Defines a function `g`, taking *m* and *n* in that order.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%26tG.%5EHsgBu-G%2FGH%7BPGGhHGgF&input=32%2C524287&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1000000000000000%2C2%0A3486784401%2C4%0A524287%2C32%0A10000000000%2C2017&debug=0)

#### How it works

```
M&tG.^HsgBu-G/GH{PGGhHG
M                         def g(G, H):
 &tG                        0 if G == 1, else …
                 PG         prime factors of G
                {           deduplicate that
          u-G/GH   G        reduce that on lambda G,H:G-G/H, starting at G
                              (this gives the Euler totient φ(G))
        gB          hH      bifurcate: two-element list [that, g(that, H + 1)]
       s                    sum
    .^H               G     H^that mod G
```

## Python 2, <s>109</s> 76 bytes

```python
import sympy
def g(n,m):j=sympy.totient(m);return m-1and pow(n,j+g(n+1,j),m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RczRCsIgFMbx@z2Fl9OdQs82FkUPE8xKwaO4E@HTmxSx2x//70uFn5GwVhdSzCy2ElLpVnsXj54gyLO/funIkZ0l7oO8ZMuvTCIczI1WkeK7lX5o/WDAyzaqKTvi9oBgtFJmlt1fJhiVQr3DiDDjhKdlJ9Rm@Q21rB8)

## Why it works

We use the following generalization of [Euler’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

**Lemma.** *n*<sup>2φ(*m*)</sup> ≡ *n*<sup>φ(*m*)</sup> (mod *m*) for all *n* (whether or not *n* is coprime to *m*).

*Proof:* For all prime powers *p*<sup>*k*</sup> dividing *m*,

- If *p* divides *n*, then because *φ*(*m*) ≥ *φ*(*p*<sup>*k*</sup>) = *p*<sup>*k* − 1</sup>(*p* − 1) ≥ 2<sup>*k* − 1</sup> ≥ *k*, we have *n*<sup>2φ(*m*)</sup> ≡ 0 ≡ *n*<sup>φ(*m*)</sup> (mod *p*<sup>*k*</sup>).
- Otherwise, because *φ*(*p*<sup>*k*</sup>) divides *φ*(*m*), Euler’s theorem gives *n*<sup>2φ(*m*)</sup> ≡ 1 ≡ *n*<sup>φ(*m*)</sup> (mod *p*<sup>*k*</sup>).

Therefore, *n*<sup>2φ(*m*)</sup> ≡ *n*<sup>φ(*m*)</sup> (mod *m*).

**Corollary.** If *k* ≥ φ(*m*), then *n*<sup>*k*</sup> ≡ *n*<sup>φ(*m*) + (*k* mod φ(*m*))</sup> (mod *m*).

*Proof:* If *k* ≥ 2φ(*m*), the lemma gives *n*<sup>*k*</sup> = *n*<sup>2φ(*m*)</sup>*n*<sup>*k* - 2φ(*m*)</sup> ≡ *n*<sup>φ(*m*)</sup>*n*<sup>*k* - 2φ(*m*)</sup> = *n*<sup>*k* - φ(*m*)</sup> (mod *m*) and we repeat until the exponent is less than 2φ(*m*).

Comment: How does this handle the case where the base and modulo isn't coprime? P.S. sympy has totient function.

Comment: @orlp I’ve added a proof. Not sure how I missed `sympy.totient`.

Comment: I see now. Nice method!

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 156 bytes

`(?)` takes two `Integer`s and returns an `Integer`, use as `(10^10)?2017` (reversed order compared to OP.)

```hs
1?n=0
m?n=n&m$m#2+m#2?(n+1)
1#_=1
n#p|m<-until((<2).gcd p)(`div`p)n=m#(p+1)*1`max`div(n*p-n)(p*m)
(_&_)0=1
(x&m)y|(a,b)<-divMod y 2=mod(x^b*(mod(x*x)m&m)a)m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZDBbsIwDIbveYqITshuy9QEEDs06guM044MSlnRqFa7ES2jSH33Lu2EmBYpyh9/v23Zp6z@OpZlT1nBhjK7TqW9NG/N@ZWFdGczeWcehDRyEgT1qbpKDoKRScfoH6M/rKmux/ODASWMI@yAQ8J41hzrpt4KMb7SDGwDOpQq2qklhqMXFqGc73R0/84dX@qFflndIzpSq9@cCLe9SthEwrUyPKUn8nTgbgIcKBTKS40S7NmO4tmFm6IEiDU@f37k0iLs8@J7b9HtwQPr/L7aU9YOUWDfzhjB@oQC0mmKkSsE7ZTw1kEWHtwwzraucnmT2lCVQ7s7@DAKv0Vyxgyp738A) (I put the cases to test in the header this time, since they use exponentiation notation.)

Curiously the slowest test case isn't the one with a speed limit (that's almost instant), but the `524287 ? 32` one, because `524287` is a much larger prime than appears in the factors of the other test cases.

## How it works

- `(x&m)y` is `` x^y `mod` m ``, or power mod, using exponentiation by squaring.
- `n#p` is the Euler totient function of `n`, assuming `n` has no smaller prime factors than `p`.

  - `m` is `n` with all `p` factors divided out.
  - If there are `k` such factors, the totient should itself get a corresponding factor `(p-1)*p^(k-1)`, which is calculated as `div(n*p-n)(p*m)`.
  - `` 1`max`... `` handles the case where `n` wasn't actually divisible by `p`, which makes the other argument of `max` equal to `0`.
- The main function `m?n` uses that when `y` is large enough, `` n^y `mod` m `` is the same as `` n^(t+(y`mod`t)) `mod` m ``, when `t` is the totient of `m`. (The `t+` is needed for those prime factors `n` and `m` have in common, which all get maximized.)
- The algorithm stops because iterated totient functions eventually hit 1.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 55 bytes

```
n_~f~1=0;n_~f~m_:=PowerMod[n,(t=EulerPhi@m)+f[n+1,t],m]
```

Examples:

```
In[1]:= n_~f~1=0;n_~f~m_:=PowerMod[n,(t=EulerPhi@m)+f[n+1,t],m]

In[2]:= f[2, 10^15]

Out[2]= 566088170340352

In[3]:= f[4, 3^20]

Out[3]= 4

In[4]:= f[32, 524287]

Out[4]= 16

In[5]:= f[2017, 10^10]

Out[5]= 7395978241
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 56 bytes

```
f(n,m)=if(m-1,lift(Mod(n,m)^((t=eulerphi(m))+f(n+1,t))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctBCoMwEIXhfU/hcgZHyIyK3XiEXiEgaOyAsSHE86dBEXzLj/@FKWqzhpwd7ORxVAe@YdrUJfj85hMtQBqXY1ti@Cp4xLrENVPCshyi7gkcCFVsLPeIr5s6qlor5iFtqXrp5D08UAwP17mk@Q8)