# The infinite power tower

Tags: code-golf, math

## The challenge

Quite simple, given an input `x`, calculate it's infinite power tower!

```
x^x^x^x^x^x...
```

*For you math-lovers out there, this is `x`'s infinite [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration).*

Keep in mind the following:

```
x^x^x^x^x^x... = x^(x^(x^(x^(x...)))) != (((((x)^x)^x)^x)^x...)
```

Surprised we haven't had a "simple" math challenge involving this!*

## Assumptions

- `x` will **always** converge.
- **Negative and complex** numbers should be able to be handled
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so **lowest bytes** wins!
- Your answers should be correct to at least **5** decimal places

## Examples

```
Input >> Output

1.4 >> 1.8866633062463325
1.414 >> 1.9980364085457847
[Square root of 2] >> 2
-1 >> -1
i >> 0.4382829367270323 + 0.3605924718713857i
1 >> 1
0.5 >> 0.641185744504986
0.333... >> 0.5478086216540975
1 + i >> 0.6410264788204891 + 0.5236284612571633i
-i >> 0.4382829367270323 -0.3605924718713857i
[4th root of 2] >> 1.239627729522762
```

---

**(Other than a more complicated challenge [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/124391/evaluate-modular-power-towers))*

Comment: I don’t think this tower converges at *x* = −2 or *x* = −0.5.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I agree, though all programs seem to have the same converging answer. Why don't they converge?

Comment: *x* = −2 gets attracted to a 8-cycle and *x* = −0.5 gets attracted to a 6-cycle. (My program still gives an answer in these cases, but it’s one of the points in the cycle and not a fixed point; this doesn’t indicate convergence.)

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Aha very interesting. You wouldn't happen to know why '8' for -2 and '6' for -0.5? Just out of curiosity of course.

Comment: You can run the iterations just as easily as I can, but here’s a picture: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tetration_period.png

Comment: You say we have to calculate the infinite power tower, but do we have to display/output it?

Comment: @kamoroso94 Yes and no. A lot of answers just have a function that generates a number, but can be outputted quite easily (usually shown in the 'Try It Online'). It really depends if it's faster to print it or to return it as a function.

Answer (score 16):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

```apl
*⍣≡⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wStR72LH3UufNS7AshXMNQzAWFDEwUNI63D2400FQ6tN1Qw8DJUAJJ6pgoah7cbayoYeoHEQDJgVSaaAA)

`*` power

`⍣` until

`≡` stable

`⍨` selfie

Answer (score 12):

## Pyth,  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

<sup>[crossed out 4 is still regular 4 ;(](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133541/39242)</sup>

```
u^Q
```

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%5EQG&input=1.414&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1.4%0A1.414%0A1.4142135623730951%0A-1%0A1j%0A1%0A0.5%0A0.3333333333333333%0A1%2B1j%0A-1j%0A1.189207115002721)

#### How it works

```
u       first repeated value under repeated application of G ↦
 ^QG        input ** G
    Q   starting at input
```

Comment: You don't need the last `G`, it will get auto-filled.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Right, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>100</s> 63 bytes

For inputs that don't converge (eg. `-2`) this won't terminate:

```hs
import Data.Complex
f x=until(\a->magnitude(a-x**a)<1e-6)(x**)x
```

Thanks a lot @ØrjanJohansen for teaching me about `until` and saving me `37` bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NDsIgEITvPsUePEAtKP4djPWiV59AjdlEqkSg2NKEt8fVcJlvMpPJvHB4a2tzNi50fYQTRpTHzgWr06SF1Iw@GsuuKA4On97E8aEZilRVyPdKiy1n5HnKDo2HBhyG8x1Y6I2PsuVwUXJdA4kiDB96WNYgVA0L2M2A@LNyQ5yvSEr4L5lQvGymZXrLXw)

Comment: You can shorten this a lot with the `until` function. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NDsIgEITvPsUePEAtKP4djPWiV59AjdlEqkSg2NKEt8fVcJlvMpPJvHB4a2tzNi50fYQTRpTHzgWr06SF1Iw@GsuuKA4On97E8aEZilRVyPdKiy1n5HnKDo2HBhyG8x1Y6I2PsuVwUXJdA4kiDB96WNYgVA0L2M2A@LNyQ5yvSEr4L5lQvGymZXrLXw "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: Neat! Did not know `until`, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40 39</s> 35 bytes

- Thanks @Ørjan Johansen for a byte: `d>99` instead of `d==99`: 1 more iteration for a lesser byte-count
- Thanks @Uriel for 4 bytes: wise utilization of the fact that `x**True` evaluates to x in `x**(d>99or g(x,d+1))`. The expression in the term evaluates to True for depth greater than 99 and thus returns the passed value.

Recursive lambda with a max-depth 100 i.e. for a depth 100 returns the same value. Actually is convergency-agnostic, so expect the unexpected for numbers with non-converging values for the function.

```python
g=lambda x,d=0:x**(d>99or g(x,d+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P902JzE3KSVRoUInxdbAqkJLSyPFztIyv0ghXQMopG2oqfm/oCgzr0QjXcNQzwTIAwA)

Comment: In the tio link, you can replace `complex('j')` with `1j`

Comment: `d>99` does one more iteration and is shorter.

Comment: save 4 bytes with `g=lambda x,d=0:x**(d>99or g(x,d+1))`, `x**True` evaluates to `x`

Comment: @Uriel, That is really smart..... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <s>37</s> <s>30</s> 27 bytes

-7 bytes from @FelipeNardiBatista.
-3 bytes from from @xnor

I don't remember much of Python anymore, but I managed to port my Ruby answer and beat the other Python 3 answer :D

```py
lambda x:eval('x**'*99+'1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fbhvzPycxNyklUaHCKrUsMUdDvUJLS13L0lJb3VBd839BUWZeiUa6hqGeiaYmF4yna4jEMczS1PwPAA)

Comment: FYI, it appears that f-strings were first introduced in Python 3.6: see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ .  (This would explain why your code didn't work for me in 3.5.2.)  Just thought I'd mention this in case anyone else was confused.

Comment: You don't need to substitute in the value of `x`, `eval('x**'*99+'1')` works

Comment: @xnor doh, of course it does :) thanks

Comment: @xnor Neat -- I applied the same thing in my Ruby answer and it somehow fixed it :)

Comment: +1, I am slapping myself for forgetting the existence of eval.... :D

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 12 bytes

```
#//.x_:>#^x&
```

Takes a floating‐point number as input.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 5 bytes

```
^^:_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03B1kohLs4qvo6LKzU5I19BQ0cvTclAU8FQzwSEDU0UdBQ0VK0UjDSBjHhDBYMsQwUgqWcKFlcwBgkbZoHEgZJAIRMFsOL//wE)

### Explanation

First, I'll show what command is being executed after parsing the `~` at the end, and the walk-through will be for the new verb.

```
(^^:_~) x = ((x&^)^:_) x

((x&^)^:_) x  |  Input: x
      ^:_     |  Execute starting with y = x until the result converges
  x&^         |    Compute y = x^y
```

Comment: The J solution is really nice here.  To break down your first line in finer grain, is it correct to say that the following happens: `(^^:_) ` creates a new dyadic verb via the power conj, then self adverb `~` makes that verb monadic, so that when given an argument `x` it's expanded to `x (^^:_) x`.  the left `x` subsequently "sticks", giving `((x&^)^:_) x` per your note, and only the right argument changes during iteration?

Comment: @Jonah Sure, when giving two arguments to a dyad with power, `x u^:n y`, the left argument is bonded with the dyad to form a monad that is nested `n` times on `y`. `x u^:n y -> (x&u)^:n y -> (x&u) ... n times ... (x&u) y`

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>79</strike> 78 bytes

```cs
x=>{var a=x;for(int i=0;i++<999;)a=System.Numerics.Complex.Pow(x,a);return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVFNTwIxEL3zK3rcDbj0a9tuluVC4kkMiQcPxkOzFmzCttoWWEP47euyEjFRBBPfoZ3MdN7rmyn9VWmdakCLcim9BzNnF05WvX1m2517@CCDLsHa6icwldpEPjhtFg@PQLqFjz/fHTv2uHvzQVXJ9cqUo0N8u6qU06VPJrZ6Wap6AE4UxmAOih5o6mK8XUsHZFHnc@sibQLQBcx1vz/KsiyPZXGCIZnZTVQPZJw7FVbOAJnvmrz30w8n1ni7VMm900HdaKOieYQSGsc5@BXDIUCJEIwxQiDDtL1w@gcBdE6iE8gyAQmjUKQ05YLySwUOpakMz8ndqwsRjr/JtQL4Uj6jNqe2FcEB6shbPphQIrDAGWEcc0gwAf02SRhMM0w5EhwRkXJ98ZzOruFjTv9hA321wSiCmFEuBIZUZKizkWLCsKAM4ZSjdt9HG7su2jXv)

I chose to iterate until `i`=999 because if I iterated until 99 some examples did not reach the required precision. Example:

```cs
Input:                      (0, 1)
Expected output:            (0.4382829367270323, 0.3605924718713857)
Output after 99 iterations: (0.438288569331222,  0.360588154553794)
Output after 999 iter.:     (0.438282936727032,  0.360592471871385)
```

As you can see, after 99 iterations the imaginary part failed in the 5th decimal place.

```cs
Input:                      (1, 1)
Expected output:            (0.6410264788204891, 0.5236284612571633)
Output after 99 iterations: (0.64102647882049,   0.523628461257164)
Output after 999 iter.:     (0.641026478820489,  0.523628461257163)
```

In this case after 99 iterations we get the expected precision. In fact, I could iterate until `i`=1e9 with the same byte count, but that would make the code considerably slower

- 1 byte saved thanks to an anonymous user.

Comment: +1 For the complex class I didn't even know that existed.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder neither did I until I googled it. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
³*$ÐL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QZi2VwxN8/v//b6htmAUA)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
->n{eval'n**'*99+?1}
```

<s>**Disclaimer**: It [seems](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematics_with_Python_and_Ruby/Complex_numbers_in_Ruby#Exponentiation) that Ruby returns some weird values when raising a complex number to a power. I assume it's out of scope for this challenge to fix Ruby's entire math module, but otherwise the results of this function should be correct.</s> **Edit**: Applied the latest changes from my [Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135656/4372) and suddenly it somehow gives the same, expected results :)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOrUsMUc9T0tLXcvSUtvesPZ/gUJatKGeSSwXlGEIZfomlmToFRcWlWgYaUJEdA2hiiCUc35uQU5qhYaBjqFm7H8A)

Comment: Take out the space after the `eval`.

Comment: Your original version failed on the complex test case because it evaled the string `"0+1i**0+1i**0+1i**..."`, which parses in the wrong way since `**` has higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen huh, you're right. I guess I was fooled by the fact that `#inspect` and `#to_s` return different values. Before submitting the initial answer I did some testing in irb and saw that e.g entering `Complex(1,2)` in the REPL would give `(1+2i)`, including the parentheses. When stringifying the value however the parentheses are not included, so the precedence, as you point out, messed it up.

Comment: I thought `eval` use was forbidden.

Comment: @V.Courtois Ok. But it's not.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 16 bytes

The input and output are stored in `Ans`.

```
Ans→X
While Ans≠X^Ans
X^Ans
End
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>36</s> 33 bytes

-*3 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam*

```r
Reduce(`^`,rep(scan(,1i),999),,T)
```

Reads from stdin. `Reduce`s from the right to get the exponents applied in the correct order.

[Try it (function)](https://tio.run/##K/qfX1CSmZ9XrKGekpmeWVKsbmtoqsmVZvs/rTQvGSSjUaEZlJpSmpyqkRCXoFOUWqBRoWNpaampoxOi@T9No7iwqETDSFPzPwA)

[Try it (stdin)](https://tio.run/##K/qfX1CSmZ9XrKGekpmeWVKsbmtoqvk/KDWlNDlVIyEuQacotUCjODkxT0PHMFNTx9LSUlNHJ0Tzv6G2YeZ/AA)

Comment: `scan(,1i)` works. Similar to how `scan(,'')` works.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam of course! sometimes my brain doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 33 bytes

```
f=(x,y=x)=>(x**y===y)?y:f(x,x**y)
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't handle imaginary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>20</s> 10 bytes

cut down to half thanks to @LuisMendo

```
t^`Gw^t5M-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQuwb08rsTUV/f/f0M9EwA)

This is my first [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) and my first time using MATL so i'm sure it could be easily outgolfed.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first answer! A few suggestions: `XII` is equivalent to `t`. You can also get rid of `XH` and `H` using the automatic clipboard `M`, that is, `ttt^\`yw^t5M-]bb-x`. And in the last part, instead of deleting the unwanted values you can use `&`, which tells the implicit display function to only show the top. So, you can use [`ttt^\`yw^t5M-]&`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6SkJC6hsjyuxNRXN1bt/39DPRMA) and save a few bytes.

Comment: Also, the first `t` is not needed, and using `G` instead of another `t` you can avoid `&` and thus leave `]` implicit: [`t^\`Gw^t5M-`](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQuwb08rsTUV/f/f0M9EwA). Hey, we've reduced byte count by a half!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks for the great tips! I have a lot to learn about MATL, but I really like it.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 4 bytes

```
‡?eẊ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%80%A1%3Fe%E1%BA%8A&inputs=1.4&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>165</s> 140 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$u=1;for($r=$a;$u-join'+'|iex){$r=[Numerics.Complex]::Pow($a,($p=$r))
$u=($p.Real,($p|% I*),-$r.Real,-($r|% I*))|% *g '.0000000'}$r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVRbb9owFH7nV/jBW@IuyXyL7RQhISFN6sO2qvQNoSlLzaUihDqJaAX8dmaTwvaAtKR58fF3Lt@5xZtiq0250KtVmBVGH@FssDtuUpPmPkwRrAekPyuMD80Apn1Yh8/Fcu198fZL/Yp2Fp38qHNtllkZjYp8s9Kv09vb@2JrnQMfbgbQINSzUawcPeh05cD9J3B3g4IQmgYKbfQGQ/a4mQMvws3nHaA5Hnq9od8DIABDfzJ@KyudR1dI13rrk4gHAKMA/NdOKSEEY1hQbg8aOzfUmoS0pUkShZngWMU8lorLDjST72m1sPL4xVQ@Ra0IaYf4IWkV0pmFOGrfnXad6ZAojuJWMXEkOCEqlpzHmCdKfKDZbnNtEwn4CjhqOWPKEkGlpElMqRRdRmCdsWViEUYtK4y5VFgJSkTMcSI7ra0tq2UTMRWWR1HMVeImFcWUCaq4IDSWxP4vrUdnd6cVKWeKKpowIanEjLLTzjGB44RySZQkzM61A@sHSa9yIrAH3@zTmGaL8OfvZ51VYGcTgZUuq1Fa6gBA/bqxsH4CAwB/OZ3RZb2q7PUznP21dJragv67vnn@ztbRXZ7Ol@vUvP0T8WxyuV@MrqVl2aPHYlyZ5Xrue7h5Rj0EDpZ5cj8e1WVV5I3xdOiKAGBcZ5kuS@BSryd4CkL94iRqpXT95ERyAdm0f3J6fC/IOZ2LazQPTeGncE1ZDj/0Dr3j8Q8)

*-7 bytes* thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!

[55 bytes without complex numbers](https://tio.run/##VZBfa8IwFMWf208RXBgNtDVJ869KQRjb25jMvYmMrovIUFrTigPnZ@9uVyvuKbn3nPu7h1uVR@vqjd1uo6J0tsXr7NRWuct3Ac7JunQBdhnOp9hFuCInKJbPebNZTSbz8giWMMBVhh0hZ@zas@/PAt8LZwGLRYhYbIxSKkmo4gIeLskgsj85TQ1NlKBGCqmN0L08LFjsXRNwEqIRH/VKxEIUsQsEAP2PxjJENFaCMSO1EJKK1Kj/rC4sh4mxIN1inqSKa81TyblWHLx3YIZgdJzElHQ4KbShRnGmpKCphugE/aAnuFFebKKXjy9bNOjke7ixdfOQ1zZE2H5X0LWfKEP4HSRn68O2geoer9HV6HvL@eLhUDflrsesZsDxFoeisHXdzV45kd2jC2UKlrcLofMMtK7/Ouy58T7eZBl40D/757b9BQ)

Comment: `[Numerics.Complex]` instead `[System.Numerics.Complex]`?

Comment: Thanks @mazzy ! I followed [your advice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xroDBOK88sQ) :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 17 bytes

```
{[R**] $_ xx 999}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjpISytWQSVeoaJCwdLSsva/tUJxYqWCElDE1k6hOg0oVaukkJZfpGCoZ6KjkKmjYKBnCiKMQUBHwVA70/o/AA)

`R**` is the reverse-exponentiation operator; `x R** y` is equal to `y ** x`.  `[R**]` reduces a list of 999 copies of the input argument with reverse exponentiation.